# Problem with QgsRasterCalculator.processCalculation() in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, raster-calculator, pyqgis-3

I have a really weird problem with a PyQGIS script which use a "for" loop. My script is doing those tasks :

- Go in a given directory and list all the files with os.listdir
- Enters a `for` loop to run tasks for each file if a condition is checked
- Process at the end a `QgsRasterCalculator.processCalculation()` function

The problem is that my `for` loop doesn't always carry out the same number of loops when I run the program. I have 6 files in my actual folder which fulfill the condition, and when I run the program, once 2 files are processed, the next time it's 5, another time 6...

After some little efforts (put some `print('test')` to locate where the error is), I know that when the `for` loop doesn't run 6 loops, it's because the `QgsRasterCalculator.processCalculation()` function doesn't work. The thing really weird is that it works one in two, so I really don't know what's appening here haha.

Here's my code :

```
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProcessingFeedback, QgsRasterLayer
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms, QgsRasterCalculator,    QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from BaseFunction import *
import os

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
feedback_process = QgsProcessingFeedback()
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())


directory = 'Y:\\1_POLD\\TEMPERATURE\\STD_MN_JOUR_LANDSAT\\sources\\'
file_list = os.listdir(directory)

entries = []

for files in file_list:

    if files.startswith('clip') and files.endswith('.tif'):
        # Loading the raster layer for the QgsRasterCalculator instance
        layer = QgsRasterLayer(directory + files, files)

        print(files)

        lyr = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        lyr.ref = layer.name() + '@1'
        lyr.raster = layer
        lyr.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(lyr)

        # Processing the calculator
        frequ_expr = lyr.ref + ' >= 2'
        frequ_calc = QgsRasterCalculator(
            frequ_expr,
            directory + '1_' + files,
            'GTiff',
            layer.extent(),
            layer.width(),
            layer.height(),
            entries
        )

        frequ_calc.processCalculation(feedback = feedback_process)
        print('test')
```

`QgsProcessingFeedback` doesn't return anything by the way.